# How to force init of a module when there is no types used in main execution assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, reflection.emit, fody

ModuleInit.Fody NuGet package is used for IL-code injection to call ModuleInitializer.Initialize().

When there are no types used in main execution assembly, other referenced assembly is not initialized with `ModuleInitializer`. Only in case of some type from the referenced assembly is used.

Direct call of `Assembly.Load("OtherAssemblyName")` doesn't trigger initialization.

So how to init module in a referenced assembly without any type usage from that assembly?

Answer (score 1):

What I do in such cases is I declare an 'assembly initializer' class, which is recognized by the calling assembly (choose any convention you like: pre-defined name, decorated with a custom `[AssemblyInitializer]` attribute, implementing an interface, whatever works for you). Then the assembly loading the other one searches for this 'assembly initializer' class and invokes its static constructor (or instantiates it, again whatever works for you).

A little bit more explanation why I prefer this way: In such cases, the assembly being loaded *usually* needs to self-register some types in a shared type registry (such as an IoC container), register some event handlers, or perform any other bootstrapping typical for add-ins or otherwise modular architectures. Having a consistent 'assembly initializer' approach gives such centralized, global opportunity to invoke such bootstrappers.

A good idea is to [hook-up into the assembly resolution process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyload%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and invoke 'assembly initializers' from a central, transparent location. However, you need to omit system assemblies, and don't forget to process already-loaded assemblies once your initialization mechanism is installed.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

1) Use a dummy Console.WriteLine(typeof(SomeTypeInsideTheAssembly).FullName);

2) If you want a more generic solution, you can use a helper to preload assemblies into your appdomain. An example can be found at:

https://github.com/Catel/Catel/blob/447f8a428fea5cb5087e97b8c58ac7cad969400a/src/Catel.Core/Catel.Core.NET40/Reflection/Extensions/AppDomainExtensions.cs#L63